# How can I reset my PostgreSQL password correctly?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have set all methods in pg_hba.conf to trust. [image]

After restarting the postgresql, service I try to connect to psql in the terminal but it still asks for a password. Any way to fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: On Windows you need to specify the host address/name in the command line: `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Please do **not** post plaint text information (e.g. `pg_hba.conf`) as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: You likely have more than one pg_hba.conf file and edited the wrong one.

Comment: @Abelisto, no you don't. [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-connect.html) "...The default behavior when host is not specified, or is empty, is to connect to a Unix-domain socket in /tmp (or whatever socket directory was specified when PostgreSQL was built). On Windows and on machines without Unix-domain sockets, the default is to connect to localhost."

Comment: @jjanes solved the issue. Thanks.